# ideal vm setup for meteor with shared folder

Tags: mongodb, meteor, virtualbox

#### situation

Hello, I run arch Linux for which there is no meteor package and have an Ubuntu server run within virtualbox for web development. There is a shared folder I mount through database. hich means I can code in to the active environment.
However, like many others, I have a problem with mongodb starting up, specifically the exit code 100.

tracing the problem:

- I created the /data/DB directory
- gave access rights to my user
- ran mongod on its own with no problems

Still I have the issue though.

#### Question

Where is the configuration file for mongodb which is installed with meteor so I can move it and do I need to create rights for a 'mongodb' user?

#### Question

What would be the ideal virtual machine for running a meteor development environment in the above set up? Having to create the data directory in the first place tells me Ubuntu server isn't ideal. some extra documentation available to answer this second question appearing on the meteor website would be beautiful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does not work correctly on virtualbox shared folders. By default, meteor creates a mongo database in your project's directory, however you can override this behavior with the `MONGO_URL` environment variable. If you set this variable, meteor will not try to start mongo and will instead connect directly to the mongo endpoint you specify. This allows you to setup mongo however you like (eg using the Ubuntu mongodb package), with data somewhere not in the shared folder.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have ended up mounting the directory as an sftp share. It's not the most elegant I must admit but, it works without any issue. Your solution is perfectly viable although it was something I was trying to avoid as then managing mongo becomes a consideration.